# How to add conditional formatting with EPPlus for Excel 2010

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, conditional-formatting

I am using Epplus library to add conditional formatting to an existing Excel spreadsheet with the following code:

```
var conditionalFormatting = worksheet.Cells[address].ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression();
conditionalFormatting.Formula = $"=IF(EXACT(A1, \"\"), IF(EXACT(B1, \"\"), TRUE, FALSE), FALSE)";
conditionalFormatting.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = errorColor;
```

This code seems to be working fine since when I open the spreadsheet with Excel 2016 I can see the appropriate behaviour.

**My Question**

On opening the same spreadsheet with Excel 2010, I get this message:

> Excel found unreadable content in 'Spreadsheet.xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this Workbook?

Recovering the contents: Excel prompts with:

> Removed Feature: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

Did this ever happen to anyone else? I think EPPlus library should work fine with Excel 2007+

Does anyone know of any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `=` sign from the `Formula`.

```
conditionalFormatting.Formula = $"IF(EXACT(A1, \"\"), IF(EXACT(B1, \"\"), TRUE, FALSE), FALSE)";
```

By adding the `=` it would result in the formula to be shown as `==IF(EXACT...` which is invalid. Formulas for conditional formatting are not stored with the beginning `=` sign. If this still works in Excel 2016, maybe it accepts/ignores the extra `=`?

Comment: This works perfectly with both Excel 2010 and 2016. Thank you very much.